# Neutered dog mating with undesexed female

Tags: dogs, behavior, breeding

We have a 11 month male Havanese who has been neutered.  We also have a 9 month female Havanese who just went through her first heat a couple of weeks ago.  Now the male is having sex with the female. They get "stuck" - I panic.  What can I do?

Comment: There are 2 things going on here, the stuck part can be addressed by the linked question. But that leaves out the part on why a neutered dog still mates.

Comment: @Flummox you could edit the existing quetsion, or write one of your own.  The OP is not asking "Why" they are asking "what to do".